# Writing the same output to multiple logs

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Is it possible to write the same output to more than one file in Batch?
My reason for wanting to do this is because I have a large batch script that produces a very detailed log. This is fine as it is, but i want to also output a trimmed back version of the log with a lot less detail in it. The Batch cannot be run multiple times either.

Say for instance I have a simple batch:

```
   Echo This is a Batch Script >> Path\File1 & Path\File2
   osql -S%SERVERNAME% -E -d%DATABASENAME% -Q%SQL% >> Path\File1
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: If all that you are doing is the single SQL query like that. No, I can't think of any way to do it. You'll probably have to write the big log and then parse it with your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the `tee` command from Unix tools. Downloadable for free from [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net). Think of it like a "T" that a plumber might put in a pipe to send water two ways.

```
osql -S%SERVERNAME% -E -d%DATABASENAME% -Q%SQL% | tee file1 file2 file3
```

Have a look at some examples as I am not entirely sure what your full processing requirement is, see [here](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/).

If you want to do some processing on one stream you can do this:

```
osql -S%SERVERNAME% -E -d%DATABASENAME% -Q%SQL% | tee unfiltered.txt | FINDSTR /v "UglyStuff" > filtered.txt
```

Comment: I don't see how that will help. He'll just get 3 copies of the same file. Someone could write a custom tee in JS/VBScript/batch that does the filtering though.

Comment: I have added an example showing that scenario hopefully.

Comment: Please see my comment above - it only takes a couple of seconds to provide feedback and thanks to people who put in the time to help answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

Second answer, because it is different...

You could use some VBScript, like this to send your osql output to both stdout and stderr and then handle the two separately. This saves you needing to install any Unix tools.

Save this as `tee.vbs`

```
REM ############################################################################
REM File: tee.vbs
REM Author: Mark Setchell
REM I don't need any Unix purists to tell me it is not functionally idential to
REM the Unix 'tee' command, please. It does a job - that's all. And I also know
REM there is no error checking. It illustrates a technique.
REM ############################################################################
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1) 
Set stderr = fso.GetStandardStream (2) 

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   REM Read in next line of input
   Line  = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   stdout.WriteLine(Line)
   stderr.WriteLine(Line)
Loop
```

Then run your osql like this:

```
osql -S%SERVERNAME% -E -d%DATABASENAME% -Q%SQL% | cscript /nologo tee.vbs 2> unfiltered.txt | FINDSTR "goodstuff" > filtered.txt
```

Basically, whatever the `tee.vbs` script writes to `stderr` gets redirected to wherever `2>` points, and whatever `tee.vbs` writes to `stdout` goes into the `FINDSTR` command.

Ideally, you could put your filtering inside the `tee.vbs` file for maximum flexibility.