# stdout to multiple processes - Windows

Tags: stdout, tee

Very similar to:
[How can I send the stdout of one process to multiple processes using (preferably unnamed) pipes in Unix (or Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942/how-can-i-send-the-stdout-of-one-process-to-multiple-processes-using-preferably)

Particularly...

```
         proc2 -> stdout
       /
 proc1
       \ 
         proc3 -> stdout
```

I have 'proc1' with some output that I would like to pass in to 'proc2' and 'proc3'.

I would not like to save the output from 'proc1' and pass that in [as the input] to two other processes, 'proc2' and 'proc3'.

There was a lot of discussion about 'tee' and I found '[wtee](http://wintee.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)'.

Alas, the following did not work:

```
proc1 | wtee (proc2 -i - <other arguments>) (proc3 -i - <other arguments>)
```

Note: The '-i -' is passed in to 'proc2' and 'proc3' so that each process knows where the input is coming from (stdout).

Is there a way I can do what I am trying to do in Windows?

Perhaps the arguments passed in to each process is why the two are not working?

Am I better off [or stuck] writing a program to do this?

Comment: Have a look at my answers here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323835/writing-the-same-output-to-multiple-logs/22324086#22324086

Comment: Tried it just now - didn't work. T_T
I think the 'tee' program in that script has the same functionality as 'wtee'.

Comment: What about modifying my tee program to read from stdin but write everything to 2 named pipes and then running the second program with `-i \pipe\1` and the other with `-i \pipe\2`?

Comment: Are named pipes supported by Windows [without having to write a program]? I was under the impression that they are not and either I would have to write my own 'pipe-writer'/'pipe-reader'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making my own pipe reader/server similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/430466/in-windows-can-i-redirect-stdout-to-a-named-pipe-in-command-line/430475#430475), except the server can output to as many clients as it chooses.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but you should be able to do something like this with named pipes. You write a VBscript called `splitter.vbs` that reads its stdin and writes to two named pipes, then start your two other processes telling them to read from the pipes.

```
proc1 | cscript /nologo splitter.vbs

proc2 -i \\.\pipe\p1
proc3 -i \\.\pipe\p2
```

Depending on whether you want the programs to start in new windows or not, you can either start 3 command prompt windows and run one in each, or re-use a single command prompt window by using `START /B`

`splitter.vbs` will look something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set p1 = fs.CreateTextFile("\\.\pipe\p1”, True)   
Set p2 = fs.CreateTextFile("\\.\pipe\p2”, True) 

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   Line  = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   p1.WriteLine(Line)
   p2.WriteLine(Line)
Loop
```

Comment: Unfortunately, batch scripts cannot read from \\.\pipe\*. :(
I do appreciate the effort, though.

Comment: Aha - I didn't know your proc2 and proc3 were batch scripts.